# Using HipHop VM on windows

Tags: facebook, virtual-machine, hiphop

I just read an [article](http://www.techgig.com/tech-news/editors-pick/Facebook-invents-a-PHP-virtual-machine-Java-World-19129) and learned about the HHVM which is built on the lines of JVM for Java. I went ahead and tried searching on the web, but found only articles about installing it on Ubuntu build 12 version.

I have been using a WAMP stack and would like to know if I can use the HHVM for any of my application. Also,I would like to understand if the HHVM can be integrated with our existing applications. Earlier an article suggested HipHop was what FB wrote to enhance their performance based on their requirements,and it may not suit yours. Is the same case with HHVM?

Comment: Looking forward for some answers!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At present, HHVM does not support Windows. The HHVM team probably will not be adding Windows support in 2013, though they might pursue it at some point in the future. The team gladly accepts code contributions from developers who want to improve HHVM's support for different platforms at https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php . You can also open a github issue at https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/issues to ask about Windows support.

Comment: Well thank you for answering a dead thread @Drew.If you can also point me how can I test the HHVM,it would be great.I have a ubuntu 12.4 configured on my **virtualbox** and want to create a POC for a demo.

Comment: If you want to run the tests that come with HHVM you can use the "hphp/test/run" script. ".travis.yml" shows what parameters you can pass to this script to run different test suites in different modes: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/blob/fb79922229af209810dfd862b2b197347c00abc2/.travis.yml .

I believe ".travis.yml" assumes the current working directory is "hphp/test".

If you're interested in running the test suites from various PHP frameworks, you can find instructions here at https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/_pages (search for "OSS PHP Frameworks Unit Testing").

Comment: Actually a better link for running the tests suites from various PHP frameworks is https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/OSS-PHP-Frameworks-Unit-Testing:-General .

Answer (score 4):

Just as an update, since this is still popular - there is an official compiling/installation guide [here at their Wiki](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-Installing-HHVM-on-Cygwin) for windows.

Full installation run-through [guide](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-Installing-HHVM-on-Cygwin).

Comment: Tried it a few months ago, doesn't really work... you run into a lot of errors, even if you follow the build instructions **religiously** . Maybe I'll try again in a few months, when more progress will be done on this.

Comment: I've to admit, i had a hard time getting it to run. Now i am using qEmu or Hyper-V to run it.